# Change value of Points earned in product data

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

I have an e-commerce website. I have implemented yith points and rewards plugin and can now see a 'points earned' option under product data tab.I have about 700+ products and I want to fill the option with a value (eg. 5) for all the products. However, I cannot see this option under Bulk edit. I tried using plugins and went through the documentations but could not find any help. How can I resolve this? Please Help.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add following code to your `functions.php` file in theme directory.

```
add_action('init', 'set_point_earned');

function set_point_earned() {
    global $wpdb;

    $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO {$wpdb->postmeta} (post_id, meta_key, meta_value)
    SELECT ID, '_ywpar_point_earned', '5' FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE post_type IN ('product','product_variation') AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} WHERE post_id = ID AND meta_key = '_ywpar_point_earned' )");
}
```

Then visit your site. After applying the changes you can remove code from `functoins.php`. If you want every product have a point by default keep code!